How to parse CSV with incorrectly separated rows to pandas dataframe
How to store properly in a pandas Datframe?
link to dataset:"https://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston"

Snippet from data
[ 21 lines of header text]
 0.00632  18.00   2.310  0  0.5380  6.5750  65.20  4.0900   1  296.0  15.30
  396.90   4.98  24.00
 0.02731   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  6.4210  78.90  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80
  396.90   9.14  21.60
 0.02729   0.00   7.070  0  0.4690  7.1850  61.10  4.9671   2  242.0  17.80
  392.83   4.03  34.70
 0.03237   0.00   2.180  0  0.4580  6.9980  45.80  6.0622   3  222.0  18.70
  394.63   2.94  33.40

# Importing
data_url = "http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston"
# Define your column names
column_names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']
boston = pd.read_csv(data_url, skiprows=21, sep =r'\s+',  names = column_names, header= None, engine='python')

boston.head(2)

Result with current approach:
>>> boston.head()
        CRIM     ZN  INDUS  CHAS    NOX     RM   AGE     DIS  RAD    TAX  PTRATIO   B  LSTAT  MEDV
0    0.00632  18.00   2.31   0.0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900  1.0  296.0     15.3 NaN    NaN   NaN
1  396.90000   4.98  24.00   NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN    NaN      NaN NaN    NaN   NaN
...


Using sep = r'\s+', it actually start to further add values in next row filling the above skipped filling with NaN

Your dataset does not represent a well-formed CSV partly because the significant data (your 14 "columns") are split over 2 lines

It's probably better to not try to process your input data as a CSV - mainly because it's not really a CSV file!
You could do this:
import requests
import pandas as pd
from itertools import cycle
from collections import defaultdict

with requests.get("http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston") as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    lines = response.text.splitlines()
    data = defaultdict(list)
    columns = [line.split()[0] for line in lines[7:21]]
    keys = cycle(columns)
    for line in lines[22:]:
        for token in line.split():
            data[next(keys)].append(token)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df.head())

Output:
      CRIM     ZN  INDUS CHAS     NOX      RM    AGE     DIS RAD    TAX PTRATIO       B LSTAT   MEDV
0  0.00632  18.00  2.310    0  0.5380  6.5750  65.20  4.0900   1  296.0   15.30  396.90  4.98  24.00
1  0.02731   0.00  7.070    0  0.4690  6.4210  78.90  4.9671   2  242.0   17.80  396.90  9.14  21.60
2  0.02729   0.00  7.070    0  0.4690  7.1850  61.10  4.9671   2  242.0   17.80  392.83  4.03  34.70
3  0.03237   0.00  2.180    0  0.4580  6.9980  45.80  6.0622   3  222.0   18.70  394.63  2.94  33.40
4  0.06905   0.00  2.180    0  0.4580  7.1470  54.20  6.0622   3  222.0   18.70  396.90  5.33  36.20


Wow, that's one badly formatted CSV.
I think your best approach is to parse it twice and take use of the fact that skiprows can take a lambda function as an input.

skiprows : int, list of int or Callable, optional Line numbers to skip
(0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row
indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
x in [0, 2].

So first parse every other row for most of the columns:
boston1 = pd.read_csv(data_url, skiprows=lambda n: n < 21 or n % 2 == 1, sep =r'\s+',  names = column_names[:-3], header= None, engine='python')

Then the last three columns separately:
boston2 = pd.read_csv(data_url, skiprows=lambda n: n < 22 or n % 2 == 0, sep =r'\s+',  names = column_names[-3:], header= None, engine='python')

And finally combine the two horizontally:
>>> pd.concat([boston1, boston2], axis=1)
        CRIM    ZN  INDUS  CHAS    NOX     RM   AGE     DIS  RAD    TAX  PTRATIO       B  LSTAT  MEDV
0    0.00632  18.0   2.31     0  0.538  6.575  65.2  4.0900    1  296.0     15.3  396.90   4.98  24.0
1    0.02731   0.0   7.07     0  0.469  6.421  78.9  4.9671    2  242.0     17.8  396.90   9.14  21.6
2    0.02729   0.0   7.07     0  0.469  7.185  61.1  4.9671    2  242.0     17.8  392.83   4.03  34.7

